# Why is Socket.io not connecting in my React Native app

Tags: javascript, react-native, socket.io

I am creating a react native app and and I'm trying to connect my client app to my server.  I am using socket-io and I'm unsuccessful in connecting the two so far.  Here is my code on the client:

```
import SocketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';

(...) 

if (result.type === "success") {
    console.log("Here 1");
    this.socket = SocketIOClient('http://localhost:1997');
    this.socket.emit('test', 'Hello world!');
    console.log("Here 2");
}
```

And this code outputs "Here 1" "Here 2"

My Server code is as following:

```
let express = require('express');
let http = require('http')
let socketio = require('socket.io');

var app = express();
var server = http.Server(app);
var websocket = socketio(server);

let port = 1997;
server.listen(port, () => console.log('listening on *:' + port));

websocket.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log("Client joined on " + socket.id);

    websocket.on('test', function(data){
        console.log('Data Receieved: ' + data);
    });
});
```

This code outputs "listening on *:1997" and then nothing else even when the client code runs.  Please help I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Need some more details. What server is the client side being served from? Are they on two different servers? Is there any console output on the server side?

Comment: All local on one server

Comment: Okay great. How is the React Native app being served? That part isn't shown in this code – I'd expect there to be an `app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});` somewhere (or something to that effect).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and changing "localhost" to the actual ip, worked like a charm for me.

So change

```
this.socket = SocketIOClient('http://localhost:1997');
```

To

```
this.socket = SocketIOClient('http://192.168.xxx.xxx:1997');
```

I got the answer from here:
[Using Socket.io with React Native and not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52806272/using-socket-io-with-react-native-and-not-working)