# Using Socket.io with React Native and not working

Tags: node.js, react-native, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to complete a homework and I need to have websocket for it. I use react native as client and node.js for server. However, even I tried all the solution suggestions on web, I couldn't get it working.

**Client**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import SocketIO from 'socket.io-client';

const connectionConfig = {
  jsonp: false,
  reconnection: true,
  reconnectionDelay: 100,
  reconnectionAttempts: 100000,
  transports: ['websocket'], // you need to explicitly tell it to use websockets
 };

export default class App extends React.Component {

   constructor() {
    super();
    this.socket = SocketIO('http://localhost:3000',connectionConfig);
    this.socket.on('connect', () => {
         console.log('connected to server');
    });
 }
```

**Server**

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');

const port = 3000;
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socketIO(server);

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(port, 'is up');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('new user connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('User was disconnected');
    });
});
```

Here are the version I am using,

> socket.io: 2.1.1
>
> express: 4.16.4
>
> socket.io-client: 2.1.1
>
> expo: 30.0.1

I want to thank you in advance for all your effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem.

> this.socket = SocketIO('http://localhost:3000',connectionConfig);

I've omitted the connectionConfig from the function call and change the way I write the local host to that.

> this.socket = SocketIOClient('http://192.168.xxxx:3000');

It now works both on android and iOS.

Comment: Thanks for this. In my case switching out localhost with my local ip was all I needed to do, no need to mess with connectionConfig for me.

Comment: I still wonder why my `this.socket.on('connect',...` is not being called.

Answer (score 0):

```
first get thiss package > socket.io-client
then 
import io from "socket.io-client";
then 
const socket = 
io.connect("http://192.168.64.194:3000");
```

Note: 192.168.64.194 this is called IP, it is changed based on your internet net work! Put your own IP into here. Where/how do you find IP? It is easy, every time when you run your app, you see this in you terminal:

```
*Metro waiting on exp://192.168.64.194:xxxx,*
```

that is it. The 3000 is the port, it should be the same in the frontend and backend.